# Django allauth with custom redirect Adapter ignoring "?next" parameter

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-allauth

I am using Django 3.2 and django-allauth 0.44

I have a custom adapter that redirects a user to their profile page upon login - however, I also want to be able to use a `?next=/some/url/` (example `/accounts/login/?next=https://127.0.0.1:8000/&page=2`) so that a user is redirected to that url if there is a `next` parameter in the `GET` arguments.

This is my custom Adapter (modified thanks to suggestions by @iklinac):

```
class MyAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    
    def get_next_redirect_url(self, request, redirect_field_name="next"):
        """
        Returns the next URL to redirect to, if it was explicitly passed
        via the request.
        """
        redirect_to = get_request_param(request, redirect_field_name)
        if not self.is_safe_url(redirect_to):
            redirect_to = None
        return redirect_to    


    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request, url=None, redirect_field_name="next", signup=False):
        ret = url
        if url and callable(url):
            # In order to be able to pass url getters around that depend
            # on e.g. the authenticated state.
            ret = url()
        if not ret:
            ret = self.get_next_redirect_url(request, redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name)
        if not ret:
            if signup:
                #ret = self.get_signup_redirect_url(request)
                return reverse('profile', kwargs={'username': request.user.username}) 
            else:
                ret = '/' # Go home ..
        return ret
```

I have had to modify my custom adapter, so that it checks for a 'next' GET parameter BEFORE going to the profile page (if no `next` parameter specified).

However, the logic in my code is somehow ignored (`next=/some/url` param is still ignored).

How can I use `?next=/some/url` with django-allauth whilst also using a custom adaptor?

Comment: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/cc0dfb7b30b22a8e68eaa35019515c5180e183f0/allauth/account/utils.py#L39

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli it seems you are following the solution I had given to you previously, as far as I see it should work. Here is some debugging info: `allauth.account.views.LoginView` in its `form_valid` method calls the `login` method of `allauth.account.forms.LoginForm` which then calls `allauth.account.utils.perform_login` which then calls `allauth.account.utils.get_login_redirect_url` which finally calls the adapters `get_login_redirect_url`. Possible issues can be you haven't set the `ACCOUNT_ADAPTER` setting to your adapter or you are using some custom login view.

Comment: Also the initial version of the adapter in this post was enough (the redirect to `next` is handled by `allauth.account.utils.get_login_redirect_url`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat you were right on both accounts. The `ACCOUNT_ADAPTER` variable in my settings.py was commented out (leaving me wondering how I am being redirected correctly); the logic flow as you described, is also correct - **HOWEVER**, the `get_login_redirect()` method on my custom adapter is called with **request **variable=`<WSGIRequest: POST '/accounts/login/'>`, **url** = `None`; `get_request_param()` in `LoginView::get_context_data()` seems to be returning the wrong value.  This is what my URL looks like: `/accounts/login/?next=https://127.0.0.1:8000/&page=2 `

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli you are specifying an absolute url to redirect to, the thing is that allauth in the adapters `is_safe_url` function passes `allowed_hosts=None` to `django.utils.http.url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme` meaning a hostname is not allowed in your url and it **must** be a relative url.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thanks for pointing that out - but the page number is still being chopped off - even though I am using `request.path` for relative paths in my template. URL: `https://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/&page=2` is deemed to have a redirect_url of '/'

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli notice the `&` in your parameter, an `&` is used to separate parameters in query strings.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I noticed that - but can I have more than one `'?'` in the URL? I thought the first parameter was appended using '?' and the following appended using a '&'.   So if I understand you correctly, my URL should be: `https://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/?page=2`   Is that a correct interpretation of what you're saying? I'm sure I tried that before ... (but I was using absolute paths though).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat It worked! Do you want to submit that as an answer? Or should I delete the question?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli I'll write an answer in some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly your original code for the adapter (from [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69080076/1) of the question) being as below was correct:

```
class MyAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        print(f"GET request dict is {request.GET}")
        return reverse('profile', kwargs={'username': request.user.username})
```

The problem is that you haven't set the `ACCOUNT_ADAPTER` setting.

Next as you say your url looks like `/accounts/login/?next=https://127.0.0.1:8000/&page=2`, the problem with this is that your redirect url is an absolute url with the hostname but allauth passes `allowed_hosts=None` to the function that verifies the safety of this url causing it to not be used. The solution to this is to either use relative urls or edit your adapter to allow certain hostnames:

```
class MyAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        print(f"GET request dict is {request.GET}")
        return reverse('profile', kwargs={'username': request.user.username})
    
    def is_safe_url(self, url):
        try:
            from django.utils.http import url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme
        except ImportError:
            from django.utils.http import (
                is_safe_url as url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme,
            )

        return url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme(url, allowed_hosts={'127.0.0.1:8000'}) # add any other hostname you might want to allow redirects to
```

Next your querystring is as follows: `?next=/&page=2` here the problem is you have an `&` which is used to separate querystring parameters. Although you say it works by replacing it with `?` ideally you should also urlencode it so that your querystring becomes `?next=/%3Fpage%3D2` (`?` replaced by `%3F` and `=` replaced by `%3D`).